# How to make the floating height of the blocks? To keep them on the same level

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Faced with a problem like that. There is one big block (let's call it container), which is divided into two parts col-4 and col-8. The container has fixed height blocks (they are at the top) and there are blocks that must be floating height. There is also a block with a scroll.

How do I make the height with a scroll to be floating? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, the code below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTB2D.png)

```css
.all-height {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.all-height__itme-one {
  background: #5bc0eb;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-two {
  background: #e7606b;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-three {
  background: #68d8d6;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.all-height__itme-three-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #e7606b;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.all-height__itme-four {
  background: #59a5d8;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-five {
  background: #ccd42c;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="all-height">
        <div class="all-height__itme-one">
          <p>This unit with fixed height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="all-height__itme-three">
          <p>Floating altitude</p>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-8">
      <div class="all-height">
        <div class="all-height__itme-two">
          <p>This unit with fixed height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-stretch">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="all-height__itme-four">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="all-height__itme-five">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, voluptatum hic modi unde laudantium quia officia totam maxime doloremque labore eius exercitationem harum minima deserunt aspernatur corporis enim beatae quis?

              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, could you clarify what you mean by "floating altitude" and "floating height"? if you want to avoid scrolling you should remove the fixed height to the container, but I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to make the columns with `Lorem ipsum` content stretch so that they match the height of the left columns, one approach I can suggest is to set an additional class to the right column and to adjust the items with flexbox:

```css
.all-height {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.all-height__itme-one {
  background: #5bc0eb;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-two {
  background: #e7606b;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-three {
  background: #68d8d6;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.all-height__itme-three-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #e7606b;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.all-height__itme-four {
  background: #59a5d8;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.all-height__itme-five {
  background: #ccd42c;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-col{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;      
}

.right-col .all-height__itme-two{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="all-height">
        <div class="all-height__itme-one">
          <p>This unit with fixed height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="all-height__itme-three">
          <p>Floating altitude</p>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="all-height__itme-three-item">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-8">
      <div class="all-height right-col">
        <div class="all-height__itme-two">
          <p>This unit with fixed height</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-stretch">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="all-height__itme-four">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="all-height__itme-five">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, voluptatum hic modi unde laudantium quia officia totam maxime doloremque labore eius exercitationem harum minima deserunt aspernatur corporis enim beatae quis?

              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, you can remove the `margin-bottom` from the `all-height__itme-three` element, because it expands the whole column and the items don't seem to be properly aligned on the bottom.